# unique id for dynamic table

Tags: php, javascript, loops

I will be generating a HTML table with data pulled from MySQL.The number of rows in my MySQL table are not fixed.

```
<?php
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['col1'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['col2'];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

Now how do I have the `table rows` and `table data` elements assigned unique `id` ??

Another loop to generate them won't work as I can't set an exit condition for the new loop as number of rows are not fixed.

Please guide me as to how to go forward about it. I can only use `Javascript` and not `JQUERY`.

Comment: Clarify your question please.

Comment: Do you want to put id attribute to TR?

Comment: Tip: use PDO instead of mysql_*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do something like this ?

```
<?php
  $i = 1;
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  { ?>
    <tr id="row<?php echo $i;?>">
      <td id="cell-left-<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $row['col1'];?></td>
      <td id="cell-right-<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $row['col2'];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
     $i++;
   } ?>
```

Please note, I have added ids `row`, `cell-left-` and `cell-right-` by myself. You may change them as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter when iterating through the rows, maybe something like this:

```
<?php
    $rowCount = 0;

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rowCount++;
        ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo 'row' . $rowCount;?>">
            <td><?php echo $row['col1'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['col2'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
```

?>

You can now select an element with

```
var rowID = 1;
document.getElementById("row" + rowID);
```

Hope this helps.